# How to match and replace multiline html file with sed

Tags: html, shell, sed

I have a text file something like this.

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    String1
                </td>
                <td>
                    String2
                </td>
                <td>
                    String3
                </td>
                    ...
                    ...
                <td>
                    StringN
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the output that I want.

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                    String1;String2;String3;... ...;StringN
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Here is my BUGGY code.**

```
sed '{
:a
N
$!ba
s|<td.*>\(.*\)</td>|\1|
}'
```

I wanted to remove all `<td>` and `</td>` tags and get all the strings delimitered by some string (I can filter those strings later using that as the delimiter charater). I used the solution given in this [URL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264344). Output does not come as I expected.

**This is the actual Code**

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/120.52.72.58/80">120.52.72.58:80</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    HTTP
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="text-danger">Transparent</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <abbr title="2016-12-15 00:07:46">12h ago</abbr>
                </td>
                <td class="small">
                    <span class="text-muted">&mdash;</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="/flags/png/cn.png" alt="China (CN)" title="China (CN)" onerror="this.style.display='none'"> <abbr title="China">CN</abbr>
                </td>
                    <td class="small">
                            Beijing
                    </td>
                    <td class="small">
                            Beijing
                    </td>
                    <td class="small">
                            China Unicom IP network
                    </td>
                <td class="small">
                        <span class="text-muted">&mdash;</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: Provide your expected output for the final HTML, and can you use `xmlstarlet`?  I can provide one in that.

Answer (score 0):

> Output does not come as I expected.

Your `sed` code does not work because the `<td.*>\(.*\)</td>` matches the part of the pattern space from the first `<td` up to the last `</td>` due to the [greediness](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of the `*` quantifier. Unfortunately, `sed` doesn't support a more modern regex flavor with ungreedy quantifiers; thus, some other tool would be more appropriate.

> I wanted to remove all `<td>` and `</td>` tags and get all the strings delimitered by some string …

If those tags are always (as in your examples) on a separate line, we can do with a simple `sed` command:

```
sed '/<\/*td.*>/d'
```

All *the strings* are thereafter delimited *by some string* which is `\n` followed by spaces.